# Pandas Datetime - Quater YY

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have a dateframe column with my dates in quarter/YY format:  2Q96, 3Q96 up to 1Q22. When I use to_datetime to convert it into standard format YYYY-MM-DD, pandas incorrectly converts the years to 2096, 2097 instead of 1996, 1997. I can write a couple of lines of code to convert the 2096, 2097 to 1996, 1997 etc. I am wondering if there is an elegant solution for this to tell to_datetime to identify the year range correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `pd.to_datetime` does support a pivot year where year has only 2 digits. You can use a custom function to convert it:

```
# 60 is used as pivot year: below -> 20XX, above -> 19XX
to_year4 = lambda x: f"{19 if int(x[-2:]) >= 60 else 20}{x[-2:]}-Q{x[0]}"

df['D'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Q'].apply(to_year4))
print(df)

# Output
      Q          D
0  2Q96 1996-04-01
1  3Q96 1996-07-01
2  1Q22 2022-01-01
```

Comment: Thank you. After searching for a while, I ended up doing what you suggested.